# How can I clean up this password generator? I'm working on making my programs easier to read

Tags: python, string, random, code-cleanup

I make use of the string library to get capital and lowercase letters, numbers, and symbols. There were symbols in there that I did not want to be in the passwords (the ones in 'unwanted_characters') so I made a function to extract only the characters I wanted.

```
import random, string

password = []
unwanted_characters = ['"', '+', '~', '`', "'", '=', '<', '>', '{', '}', ';', ':', '[', ']', '.', 
',', '^', ')', '(']
wanted_characters = []


class random_pass:
    def __init__(self, no_of_characters):
        self.wanted_characters = wanted_characters
        self.no_of_characters = no_of_characters

    def desired_characters(self):
        for char in string.printable:

            if char not in unwanted_characters:
                self.wanted_characters.append(char)
        return self.wanted_characters


    def random_everything(self):

        for letter in range(self.no_of_characters + 1):
            result = random.choice(self.wanted_characters)
        
            password.append(result)

        return password


    def get_result(self):
        for readable_password in password:
            print(readable_password, end='')


max_characters = int(input("Enter the lenght of your password: "))


random_password = random_pass(max_characters)
random_password.desired_characters()
random_password.random_everything()
random_password.get_result()
```

Comment: If code is complete and working, it should be on [codereview.se] instead. This site is primarily for fixing broken code. Note though that they also like a small example to show how code is used, and some background about the purpose.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on codereview.stackexchange.com, rather than here.